# How should we use dependency injection with React.js?

Tags: oop, dependency-injection, reactjs

I'm looking for ideas to use Dependency injection with React.js

Imagine I have ClassA.js and ClassB.js, then ClassC.js requires an instance of ClassA and another of ClassB.

In some programming languages, it would be accomplished like this:

```
var instanceC = new ClassC( new ClassA(), new ClassB );
```

My question is, how it should be in React.js?

Comment: What is a specific scenario and how would it be used in your project?

Comment: It has to do with Unit Testing, when you connect classes through dependencies you could mock the dependencies so you can achieve "Unit Test". So applies for any case where a React Class or React Object if name bothers you, depends on another React Object. @WiredPrairie

Comment: Have you tried any options? As your question is currently written, this reads more like an opinion question than a programming question. Even implementation details of specific JavaScript dependency injection libraries are going to differ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing messages between components in React.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664534/passing-messages-between-components-in-react-js)