# Passing messages between components in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I had a few questions about the communication between React.js components. This is in context to without the use of redux. Here is what my component hierarchy looks like.

```
       App
      /  \
     /    \
    |      |
    ▼      ▼
 Board   Dashboard
   |
   ▼ 
 Cell
```

Below are a few assumptions/patterns that i use for components to communicate.

1. If we need to pass messages from a parent component to child
   components we do that using props. For example, while creating a
   Board we pass rows, cols as props.

   ```
   <Board rows={5} cols={5} />
   ```
2. If we need to pass messages from a child component to parent
   components we do it by passing a callback. For example we pass a
   play() callback from Board to Cell. Within Cell, we set the onClick
   handler to be the passed callback i.e. play().

   ```
   <Cell onClick={this.props.play(this.props.id)} />
   ```
3. The open question i had was how can be pass messages between sibling
   components (example Dashboard to Cell). One use-case is resetting my
   Board component when a reset button within Dashboard component is
   clicked. Here is what reset button within Dashboard looks like. My
   question is once the reset message reaches App component, whats the
   best practice to pass it down to Board?

   ```
   <input type="button" value="reset" onClick={this.props.reset} />
   ```

Would be great to get some feedback on 1 and 2. Also, the best practice for 3.

Comment: 1 & 2 are the correct way to handle that use cases. As for 3, if the components are siblings, you can use a callback from the parent (see http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#5-parent-component)
if they are not siblings, there is a good sign you should move the variable into a shared state managed by redux or other similar state managers.

Comment: @GiacomoCosimato i really like that link. Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

**Redux**

This is the exact reason why Redux is so cool. If you're using Redux, then all of these components have one single thing in common; they're all reading their values from the application state. The flow that I would use, is as follows:

1. User clicks on the reset button that lives inside the Dashboard Component
2. The function associated with that click does only one thing. Dispatches a "RESET_BOARD" action
3. In the reducer, the RESET_BOARD action resets the state for the board.
4. When the re-render occurs, the board is passed in props, just like before, only empty state is passed into it.

**No Redux**

If you've got no redux at hand, then the callback approach from the parent is the sensible way to go. If you're maintaining state in the `App` component, the App then resets its state and triggers a re-render manually. This will cause the Board to be re-rendered with different props.

Comment: Redux is cool, but you can always implement or use some other kind of global event system if the application becomes larger and you don't always want all the information to flow through the whole virtual DOM structure.

Comment: @Tommos : you have reason.. I hate redux too .. that;s why all my react projects are done without React. >.... it is enough to make a smooth communication among components when it is needed :

Comment: @Tommos If it's performance you're worried about, Redux is pretty darn quick, but I appreciate different use cases and all that! I'm a big Redux fan, but mostly because I tend to think more about maintainability and scalability, which is where Redux shines quite nicely.

Comment: redux is a global and local state management. Sending messages might have other purposes like asking all subscribers to execute a command. I think we are not limited to redux but any library with a publisher-subscriber pattern may serve in these kind of scenarios. A simple example is here: https://davidwalsh.name/pubsub-javascript

Answer (score 0):

But also , it is  restriction ;  communication between two components is restricted in 3 cases  :

1. Parent updates Child :
2. Child updates parent :
3. siblings (Brothers) updates each other (brother)

---

Let's locate your question now..
 Your question is about the 3rd case :

## The main idea is to make the grand-parent (`App`) as proxy to transfer communication .

---

```
               App
               /  \
              /    \
             |      |
             ▼      ▼
          Board   Dashboard
            |
            ▼ 
          Cell
```

### Dashboard.js

```
reset(event) {
  //.... local calls (concerning Dashboard or its children )
 // then , external calls (concerning outside Dashboard)
 if(this.props.onReset) this.props.onReset(event);
}

<input type="button" value="reset" onClick={this.reset} />
```

### App.js (the 1ˢᵗ grand-parent between [`Dashboard`, `Board>Cell`]) :

```
onDashboardReset(event) {
  this.setState({dashboardIsReset: true})
}

<Dashboard   onReset={this.onDashboardReset} />
<Board   dashboardIsReset={this.state.dashboardIsReset} />
```

### Board.js :

```
   // ... has props  `dashboardIsReset` and forward it to its children (`Cell`) if needed
```